# Custom LoginView in Django 2

Tags: django, django-2.0

I am trying to customise the authentication and view in Django 2 but the problem is that if the user is already authenticated the login form is still shown and it is not redirected to the appropriate URL. To get over this I have done the following:

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):

    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_staff and has_2fa(self.request.user):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('{}'.format(self.request.GET.get('next', 'portal_home'))))
        else:
            return self.initial.copy()

    def form_valid(self, form):

        if self.request.user.is_staff and not has_2fa(self.request.user):
            logger.info('is staff but does not have 2FA, redirecting to Authy account creator')
            auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
            return redirect('2fa_register')
        auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

But the `HttpResponseRedirect` in `get_initial()` does not redirect to the `/portal/` page. I have also tried `redirect('portal_home')` but nothing happens or do I need to write a custom `dispatch`?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overriding `get()` clears the problem see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ProcessFormView

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    """
    Custom login view.
    """

    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_staff and has_2fa(self.request):
            return redirect('{}'.format(self.request.GET.get('next', 'portal_home')))

        return super(CustomLoginView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):

        if self.request.user.is_staff and not has_2fa(self.request):
            logger.info('is staff but does not have 2FA, redirecting to Authy account creator')
            auth_login(self.request, form.get_user(), backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
            return redirect('2fa_register')

        return super(CustomLoginView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score -3):

@Akshay i have found a clean and more pragmatic solution. LoginView has an attribute "*redirect_authenticated_user*" and just set the URL name/path.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Okay @Gourav thanks for that. But still it doesn't mean that my answer is irrelevant to the question nor misleading to the main topic.

Comment: Well, questions and comments have different semantic meaning. On StackOverflow, when we have enough data and we're sure that and an answer is complete and answers the question properly, we add it to the question. Remember that StackOverflow is a forum but is different from the other ones, ask questions, get answers, no distractions. Here, you have a clean and more programatic solution that `LoginView` has... but this doesn't clearly answers the question, instead you would have commented(when you have enough repo) on @Akshay 's post to point out this problem