# Django custom LoginView not logging user in

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm fairly new to Django, but I'm trying to build a customized authentication system by subclassing the generic Django authentication components. The main issue is that my custom LoginView does not seem to do anything besides refresh the page.

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm, ReadOnlyPasswordHashField, AuthenticationForm, UsernameField
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _
from .models import CustomUser

BUREAU_CHOICES = [  ('HR', 'Human Resources'),
                    ('CRT', 'Creative'),
                    ('ACC', 'Accounting'),]

class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    bureau = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=BUREAU_CHOICES)
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True, 'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'current-password', 'placeholder': 'Password'}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password',)
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .forms import CustomAuthForm

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = CustomAuthForm
    authentication_form = CustomAuthForm
    template_name = 'users/login.html'
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='users'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

So I've read answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879319/custom-loginview-in-django-2), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657508/how-to-properly-customize-django-loginview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761409/how-to-make-a-login-view-for-django-custom-user) which all seem to involve overriding methods from the superclass `LoginView`. When I rewrite my `CustomLoginView` to override a method, they are not being called. For example:

**views.py**

```py
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = CustomAuthForm
    authentication_form = CustomAuthForm
    template_name = 'users/login.html'

    def form_valid(self, request):
        print(self.request)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This does nothing. I can't seem to find any reference to which methods I need to override and within which to place login logic.

Comment: Just to be sure: you are calling `return super().form_valid(form)` at the end of your `CustomLoginView`'s `form_valid` method?

Comment: Yes. I've added more to `form_valid`. The `print` call is just a placeholder.

Comment: @Bjorn can you explain why calling `return super().form_valid(form)` is necessary?

Comment: You have to call it because the `LoginView` (which you are extending) already has a `form_valid` method defined. If you do not call `super()`, the logic defined in `LoginView.form_valid` will never be executed. See: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L90

Comment: @Bjorn even with the `super()` call, nothing from the`form_valid` method executes, either in the subclass or parent class. Any ideas as to why?