# Multiple auth login pages in Django

Tags: django

I have multiple apps in one django project

```
/user
/manager
/business`
```

Each needs a separate set of login and registration. How do I use django.contrib.auth to satisfy this?

I have urlpatterns in main are:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/',    admin.site.urls),
    path('user/',     include('user.urls')),
    path('user/',     include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('manager/',  include('manager.urls')),
    path('manager/',  include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('business/', include('business.urls')),
    path('business/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Urlpatterns in the apps are like those:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

and I have different views for `login` and `register`, also have different templates in each app: `/templates/register/register.html` and `/templates/register/login.html`

However, login and register views seem to be shared between apps. Is there a way to separate them with ease?

Comment: I have not fully understood what you are trying to achieve. But of course you can create different views for login and registration in your apps. However, if your urls have the same name in the apps you will get unexpected behaviour. Have you considered using [namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

Comment: @Chris. Thank you. I need a separate login and registration for each app. They could use the same model, but need to be loaded from different urls and have different sets of views and templates. I re–worded the question to be more to the point.

Comment: You can assign them different auth groups.

Comment: @Lex Do you mean: If a user logs in to the user app he is not autmatically logged in for the manager app etc?

Comment: @Chris Exactly, they are in different groups, so there is a check for that in each app

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest you make use [namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) in your urls so you don't get any conflicts with the names in your urls. So add `app_name` to the urls.py of your apps, e.g.

```
#user urls.py

app_name='user'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
```

Then something like `{% url 'user:register' %}` will point to register view of your user app, `{% url 'manager:register' %}` will point to the register view of your manager app and so on.

If you have defined individual login views for each app the same goes for these views too, providing you have imported the correct views in you apps urls.py.

As you are also including the django.contrib.auth.urls in each of your apps there is of course a second 'login/' path coming from the default path in the auth.urls. However, as far as I know the resolution of urls is done top down by django, so if you keep the order of urls as in your post your custom 'login/' will be hit first and used. So no problem with that.

Where I see a problem is with your templates. If I understand it correctly all are located in a `templates/register/` folder in your apps. The django template loader does not differentiate between a `register.html` template in your user app and a `register.html` template in your manager app. So it is likely that you do not get the correct template. What I would suggest is moving the templates to an app specific subfolder, e.g. `/templates/user/register`. Then you can fetch the correct templates in your views (e.g. 'user/register.html').

I understand that you have individual app specific views. Of course you can always subclass the views django provides and adapt them to your needs. For instance by overriding the `form_valid()` method of the `LoginView`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879319/custom-loginview-in-django-2) SO post provides an example.

If on the other hand you want to use the default django login view just with a custom template you can pass the template as a kwarg to your view. E.g.:

```
# user urls.py

from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

app_name='user'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='user/login.html'), name='login'),
    # more patterns
]
```

If you want to redirect to some custom site after successful login you can add an input called 'next' to your login form containing the url to where to redirect, e.g.

```
<!-- user/login.html -->

<form action="{% url 'user:login' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/user/index/">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

In your apps you will propably be using the [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) decorator or something similar to check whether the user is allowed to access the view in that app.

Comment: Specifying app name in a folder structure works for all but contrib.auth. It insists in finding it under /templates/register/login.html and register.html. This, in turn, does not allow folder structure you suggested, and the problem persists: templates get mixed up between the apps. Thinking of giving up on built in auth altogether. Would have written auth from scratch by now.

Comment: @Lex Not sure. As demonstrated in my answer: You can pass custom templates to Django`s build in LoginView et. al.